# Java stream - filter into three separate lists/ Or groupBy but only if in enum

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm not sure if it's possible to do this in streams. but the problem is simple with for loop and multiple ifs but would like to move to streams.
I essentially want to split a list into 3 different lists based on their countries if the country is in an enum.

So I have an enum of 3 value say countries so -> countries = {Algeria, India, Spain}.

I have a list of say people objects where `person.getCountry` returns their country.

I have 3 resulting lists i want to populate

```
List <String> algeriaList;
List <String> indiaList;
List <String> spainList;
```

I want to filter the list if they are in the countries enum and then split it into 3 different lists: `[algeria{}, india{} and spain{}]` depending on the country.

I know it can be done simply using for loop with if statements but would prefer to use stream.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

First filter the list to contain only people in the countries you are interested in:

```
Set<CountryType> COUNTRIES_OF_INTEREST = Set.of(ALGERIA, INDIA, SPAIN);

peopleList.stream()
    .filter(p -> COUNTRIES_OF_INTEREST.contains(p.getCountry())
```

then collect, grouping by the country:

```
    .collect(groupingBy(Person::getCountry));
```

which gives you a `Map<CountryType, List<Person>>`.

Comment: I would probably use an `EnumSet` in this case